# Type imports don't seem to be working for me in Isabelle2016

Tags: isabelle

I'm a complete beginner to Isabelle, and I must be doing something wrong, as the following seemingly simple test code just doesn't compile for me:

```
theory testit
imports 
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Inner_Product"
begin

  thm inner_zero_left
  typ "real_inner"
end
```

In the jedit interface the thm command appears to be working fine (so it's seeing theorems in the Inner_Product import) but the real_inner typ is not. It's complaining

```
Undefined type name: "real_inner"⌂
Failed to parse type
```

I get the same error if I try to use real_inner in a theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`real_inner` is not a type; it's a type class. If you mean ‘a type of the typeclass `real_inner`’ you need to use a free type variable with the sort annotation `real_inner`:

```
typ "'a :: real_inner"
```